# trying to use an API key on a different page then my server.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am trying to take my API_KEY from a .env file which i am requiring from the server.js. However, im using my ajax API call on a different js file thats NOT the server file. How would i go about taking my api key from .env -> server.js -> app.js(file im calling the api with)

Comment: Import or `require`?

Comment: iv tried that. Iv done a module.export with the API key which i required from the .env on my server, then i try to inport { apiKey } from "/file" and it wont go. If i try to just do a require() from the app.js where im calling the API key, it console errors saying i cant require a non server js file

Comment: ```const apikey = require('../../../env.json').API_KEY``` or something like this doesn't work??? Also If you could show some code, this might be helpful so that we can see how you're trying to access the file.

Comment: Michael, thank you for your suggestion. Im doing the require in the server.js file and then consoling it over in the app.js file now. Im receiving a response using 'console.log(process.env)' but when i do 'console.log(process.env.API_KEY)` it returns undefined. Here is the structure: .env ` API_KEY=&key=AIzaSyC4lWI9kHf7QhSdd-cF9m59SbITCa8jZ30 ` server ` require('dotenv').config(); console.log(process.env.API_KEY) ` app.js `console.log(process.env.API_KEY) ` -- which returns undefined. console.log(process.env) returns data, but it does not show the API_KEY

Comment: Please check the env variable name- how you are using in your file. Env variables are case sensitive @CorbinBrockbank